# ContextProgation don't work with doOnNext() after KafkaSender.send()

Tags: java, project-reactor, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I set up context Propagation when http request come in filter like below.

```
public static <T> Mono<T> wrapMDC(Mono<T> mono, Map<String, Object> mdcMap) {
        mdcMap.forEach((key, value) -> registerMDC(key));
        Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation();
        return Mono.defer(() -> mono.contextWrite(Context.of(mdcMap)));
    }

public static void registerMDC(String mdcKey) {
        Supplier<String> getMDC = () -> MDC.get(mdcKey);
        Consumer<String> putMDC = value -> MDC.put(mdcKey, value);
        Runnable removeMDC = () -> MDC.remove(mdcKey);

        ContextRegistry.getInstance().registerThreadLocalAccessor(mdcKey, getMDC, putMDC, removeMDC);
}
```

It work fine when thread change by Mono.delay(Duration), but this below code don't work, MDC lose any context that I put above.

```
private final KafkaSender<String, String> kafkaPublisher;

    public Mono<SenderResult<String>> sendMessage(
            String messageKey, CbsPaymentRequest message, String topic) {
        ProducerRecord<String, CbsPaymentRequest> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, messageKey, message);
        return Mono.defer(
                () -> {
                    log.info("MDC context map still here");

                    return kafkaPublisher
                            .send(Mono.just(SenderRecord.create(record, messageKey)))
                            .doOnNext(
                                    r -> {
                                        
                                        log.info("MDC context map EMPTY");
                                    })
                            .next();
                });
    }
```

In doOnNext(), when I use MDC.getCopyOfContextMap(), it's empty.

Why it don't propagate context here, please help me, thank you !!

I try this and it can to get the map of MDC, but I don't make sure MDC will don't polute.

```
return kafkaPublisher
                            .send(Mono.just(SenderRecord.create(record, messageKey)))
                          **.contextCapture()**
                            .doOnNext(
                                    r -> {
                                        
                                        log.info("MDC is propagated");
                                    })
                            .next();
```